# Como desativar a main form quando outra foi aberta

Tags: vb.net

Desativar a main form quando outra foi aberta sem fechar a mesma para poder utilizar a segunda form que foi aberta mas não poder clicar na main form

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Openlistaclientes.Click
    Form_ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Comment: Isso é chamado [**Multiple-Document Interface (MDI)**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications) é uma tecnologia que o **.net** legou do **Delphi** e serve para criar janelas "modais" que comumente são chamadas de "dialog"

Answer (score -1):

Experimenta isto.

```
NomeDoForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Tinha-me enganado no lugar que metia isso mas já sabia como era obrigado

Comment: user111359, quando postar uma resposta, mesmo que esteja correta, explique detalhadamente o motivo. Assim, a dúvida é sanada corretamente, além evita comentários "Mas porque dessa forma ?"